# Cómo crear un programa en lenguaje C que imprima en pantalla los números que hay entre dos números introducidos por el usuario, y los sume

Tags: c

Diseñar el diagrama de flujo de un programa que imprima todos los
números que hay entre dos números introducidos por el usuario
comenzando por el menor y su suma. Implementar el programa en
lenguaje C.

Soy MUY nuevo y no entiendo las estructuras, no pido que se haga el ejercicio entero, solo un poco de ayuda y guia

No entiendo sobre todo la parte de hacer que se sumen los números comprendidos.
EN LENGUAJE C POR FAVOR

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda y la atención.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
  int a, b, suma=0;
  printf("Introduzca una variable inicial, y una final\n");
  scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
  while(a <= b)
  { 
    if(a %1 == 0)
    {
      printf("%d\n", a);
    }
    a++;
    for()
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hacer? Muestra el código que llevas hecho hasta ahora, por poco o malo que sea, dinos qué errores te salen, qué tienes en mente... No hacemos trabajos de la escuela, pero sí ayudamos cuando vemos un mínimo de esfuerzo. El 99% de los que estamos aquí hacemos esto que nos pides en 1 minuto, pero es que si lo hacemos no aprenderías. La única manera de aprender a programar es **PROGRAMANDO**. Por eso, te animo a que lo intentes, te pegues con ello, pienses, te frustres y al final consigas la satisfacción al ver que funciona lo que querías hacer.

Comment: Buenas, estoy cursando el primer curso de ingenieria indormática, llevo 5 horas solo con este ejercicio, sé que tengo las piezas del puzzle pero no consigo encajarlas, he hecho que el programa me lea los números que hay entre dos números introducidos por el usuario, pero no sé sumarlos. He editado la pregunta con el codigo, lo que pasa que no me deja separarlo y esta todo apelmazado. No pido en absoluto que se me haga el ejercicio, sería una falta de respero, solo pido ayuda porqué no consigo relacionar conceptos ni conseguir hacer que se sumen con bucles for while o break. Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: La comunidad no es una bola de cristal a la que le cortas y pegas el enunciado del trabajo o tarea que tu debes hacer, para luego recibir el fuente del programa desarrollado por correo electrónico. Decir "No pido que me lo hagan todo" por mera educación cuando en realidad pones el enunciado completo junto con TOOODO el código sin aislar la parte en que tienes problemas o no te funciona o si dividir el.problema en partes, esperando que mágicamente alguien se tome el trabajo de realizar el análisis que tu debiste hacer; desvirtua tu frase inicial

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que te falta ahí es sumar los números que vas mostrando. Si necesitas almacenar un resultado en algún sitio, entonces debes usar una variable:

```
while(a <= b)
{ 
  printf("%d\n", a);
  suma += a;
  a++;
}
```

Claro, el resultado de la suma no lo conoces hasta que no has terminado de iterar, así que el resultado lo mostramos después de finalizar el `while`:

```
printf("%d\n", suma);
```

Y ya estaría. Bueno, un consejo antes de terminar, reemplaza el bucle por un `for`. El bucle `for` es más legible cuando se trata de iterar entre dos límites conocidos:

```
for(int n=a; n<=b; n++)
{
    printf("%d ", n);
    suma += n;
}

printf("%d\n", suma);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y la respuesta, lo intentaré así. Buen día!